# Which part of my program is in the wrong loop? JAVA

Tags: java

The project is to create a program that takes input from the user in JOption Pane and checks if a number is prime or not. The program is supposed to loop until the user enters 0, which triggers the program to calculate max, min, sum, count, and average.

Ive completed 99% of the assignment, except the first number that I enter does not get printed out like the others but it still gets included in calculations

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Assignment4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Main Method

        userInput(); 


    }


    public static void userInput() {

    int number;
    int sum;           
        int count;                          // declaring variables
        int max= 0;
        int min= 1;
        float average; 


        String userNumber;              // Number typed by user


        sum = 0;                        // start at 0 for sum
        count = 0;                      // start at 0 for counter



                // prompt user to enter a positive number


        userNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit");


                        // convert  to int  


            number = Integer.parseInt(userNumber);  


            // if the number entered is positive and not 0, the loop repeats


            while ( number != 0 && number > 0)  {  


                sum += number;           

                // starting count and sum at 0

                count++;  

                // repeating user input prompt unless 0 is entered

                // storing values for min and max as we go

                if (number > max)max=number;
                if (number < min & number != 0)min=number;
            userNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit");  
                number = Integer.parseInt( userNumber );

                // checking if number entered is prime or not

                int i,m=0,flag=0; 

                m=number/2;      

                if(number==0||number==1){  

                 System.out.println(number+" is not a prime number"); 

                }else{  

                 for(i=2;i<=m;i++){     

                  if(number%i==0){   

                   System.out.println(number+" is not a prime number");      

                   flag=1;      
                   break;      
                  }      
                 }      
                 if(flag==0){ System.out.println(number+" is a prime number"); }  
                }

            } 

            if ( count != 0 ) {  


           // as long as one number is entered, calculations are done below


                // calculate average of all numbers entered

                average = (float) sum / count;


                // printing out the results

                System.out.printf("The average is : %.3f\n", average);
                System.out.println("The sum is : "+sum);
                System.out.println("The count is : "+count);
                System.out.println("The max is : "+max);
                System.out.println("The min is : "+min);


           }






    }
}
```

i need the first entry to print like the rest, please help me find where to put in the loop

Comment: am i just missing a do loop in front of the first JOptionPane prompt? im lost

Comment: you may remove the first prompt (outside the loop), use "while(true)" and add a break statement after all processing is done: "if (number != 0 && number > 0) break;"

Comment: Move this code `userNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit");  
                number = Integer.parseInt( userNumber );` to the bottom of your while loop.

Comment: I don't like this solution.  For clarity, user input should be collected first, then processed.  Having the loop rely on previous values of user input like this is pretty clumsy.

Comment: @ScaryWombat if he simply moves that statement to the bottom of loop, he would get "number not initialized" error

Comment: @mangusta No, it is also used before the loop.

Comment: @markspace I agree with you on this point

Comment: @ScaryWombat it is never used before the loop, there's only one line with "number" and you suggested moving it to the bottom

Comment: the user input is a positive integer. the output is the number, plus whether its prime or not.

Comment: for example i enter 4, 5 ,6 and 0 to quit. it should say whether 4, 5 and 6 are prime numbers or not, then calc avg, sum, count, total, etc

Comment: @mangusta - with all the spacing it is hard to see, but it is there after ` // prompt user to enter a positive number`

Comment: I dont know how else to write it, moving that code to the bottom actually causes more errors

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more what you need?  What input do you give it and what output do you see?

I noticed that you're adding numbers before the call to `JOptionPane`, is it possible that you have `count` larger by one than your actual count of numbers?  Your indentation is terrible, you should clean it up, I'm having trouble reading the code period.

```
// 1 START OF LOOP
        while ( number != 0 && number > 0)  {  

// 2 ADD NUMBER TO SUM
            sum += number;           

            // starting count and sum at 0

            count++;  

            // repeating user input prompt unless 0 is entered

            // storing values for min and max as we go

            if (number > max)max=number;
            if (number < min & number != 0)min=number;

// 3 THEN GET INPUT.  WHAT???

        userNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your program. The reason why the first number is never considered is that you have

```
userNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit");  
number = Integer.parseInt( userNumber );
```

two times in your code (before the while loop and in the while loop).

I would suggest to initialize number with Integer.MAX_VALUE: `number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Then remove

```
userNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer or 0 to quit");  
number = Integer.parseInt( userNumber );
```

before the while loop.

There is a `&` missing in `if (number < min & number != 0)min=number;`

=>

```
if (number < min && number != 0) {
  min=number;
}
```

The condition in the while loop can be simplified by writing `while ( number > 0)  {` because `> 0` means `!= 0` too.

I would also suggest to write your code a little better for readability. Always use curly braces for conditions (`if`), even when you only execute one line if the condition is true.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more help but you should be able to solve this assignment now on your own :)

Comment: its due in 10 min but thanks anyways for the help. i got close enough